# delegate event selector as nth element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach click event for a button that loads dynamically a Div tag.I am trying with delegate event on the parent Dev tag. The on click should be attached to nth (lets say 6) children div tag.

```
$(".navigation-bar").delegate('.navigation-bar > :nth-child(6)',"click",function() {
..
})
```

Above code is not attaching event to children div. But It works when I ran this code from console after entire page loaded.

Comment: Did you try [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of the deprecated `delegate()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rw69od92/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code works in the console after loading, then it's likely that your script is running before the DOM has finished loading. First test if that's the case by logging the elements at play right above where you are running your code:

```
console.log( $(".navigation-bar")[0] ); //this could likely be undefined
console.log( $('.navigation-bar > :nth-child(6)')[0] ); //and this is likely undefined
```

If they are undefined, make sure that your script runs at the end of your body element, or even better, run all of your code inside of jquery's ready function: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/